# WaTor Code in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, game, simulation

I just coded a version of [WaTor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wa-Tor), a population simulation game in which fish and sharks move around, breed, and eat each other. I am wondering how I did and if there are better ways to do some of the things I am doing, specifically on the move methods for the sharks and the fish.

**Animal**

```
package WaTor;

abstract class Animal {

private int x;
private int y;
private int type;
private int SIZE;

Animal(int xcoord, int ycoord, int t, int size) {
    x=xcoord;
    y=ycoord;
    type=t;
    SIZE = size;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public void moveX(int dx) {
    x = x + dx;
    if(x > SIZE - 1) {
        x = 0;
    }
    if(x < 0) {
        x = SIZE - 1;
    }
}

public void moveY(int dy) {
    y = y + dy;
    if(y > SIZE - 1) {
        y = 0;
    }
    if(y < 0) {
        y = SIZE - 1;
    }
}

public void moveUp() {
    moveX(-1);
}

public void moveDown() {
    moveX(1);
}

public void moveLeft() {
    moveY(-1);
}

public void moveRight() {
    moveY(1);
}

abstract boolean canBreed();
abstract boolean hasStarved();
}
```

**Fish**

```
package WaTor;

import java.util.Random;

class Fish extends Animal {

private static final int TYPE = 1; 
private static final int canBreed = 4;
private int breedAge;


Fish(int xcoord, int ycoord, int size) {
    super(xcoord,ycoord,TYPE,size);
    breedAge = 0;
}

public void moveUp() {
    moveX(-1);
    breedAge ++;
}

public void moveDown() {
    moveX(1);
    breedAge ++;
}

public void moveLeft() {
    moveY(-1);
    breedAge ++;
}

public void moveRight() {
    moveY(1);
    breedAge ++;
}

public boolean canBreed() {
    return breedAge == canBreed;
}

public void incBreedAge() {
    breedAge++;
}

public boolean hasStarved() {
    return false;
}

}
```

**Shark**

```
package WaTor;

import java.util.Random;

class Shark extends Animal {

private static final int TYPE = 2;
private static final int hasStarved = 4;
private static final int canBreed = 2;

private int starveTime;
private int energy;

Shark(int xcoord, int ycoord, int size) {
    super(xcoord,ycoord,TYPE,size);
    starveTime = 0;
    energy = 0;
}

public void moveUp() {
    moveX(-1);
    starveTime ++;
}

public void moveDown() {
    moveX(1);
    starveTime ++;
}

public void moveLeft() {
    moveY(-1);
    starveTime ++;
}

public void moveRight() {
    moveY(1);
    starveTime ++;
}

public boolean hasStarved() {
    return starveTime == hasStarved;
}

public boolean canBreed() {
    return energy == canBreed;
}

public void resetEnergy() {
    energy = 0;
}

public void resetStarveTime() {
    starveTime = 0;
}

public void incEnergy() {
    energy++;
}

public void incStarveTime() {
    starveTime++;
}
}
```

**Ocean**

```
package WaTor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

class Ocean {

private Animal[][] ocean;

private int numFish;
private int numSharks;
private int SIZE;

private ArrayList<Fish> fish;
private ArrayList<Shark> sharks;
private ArrayList<Shark> sharksToRemove;
private ArrayList<Shark> sharksToAdd;
private ArrayList<Fish> fishToAdd;

private Random random;

Ocean(int size, int f, int s) {
    SIZE = size;
    numFish = f;
    numSharks = s;
    random = new Random();
    ocean = new Animal[SIZE][SIZE];
    fish = new ArrayList<Fish>();
    sharks = new ArrayList<Shark>();
    sharksToRemove = new ArrayList<Shark>();
    sharksToAdd = new ArrayList<Shark>();
    fishToAdd = new ArrayList<Fish>();
    fillOcean();
    for(Fish fishy : fish) {
        addFish(fishy);
    }
    for(Shark sharky : sharks) {
        addShark(sharky);
    }
}

private void fillOcean() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numFish; i++) {
        int x = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        int y = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        addNewFish(x, y);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < numSharks; j++) {
        int x = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        int y = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        addNewShark(x, y);
    }
}

private void addFish(Fish fish) {
    ocean[fish.getX()][fish.getY()] = fish;
}

private void addShark(Shark shark) {
    ocean[shark.getX()][shark.getY()] = shark;
}

private void addNewFish(int x, int y) {
    Fish aFish = new Fish(x, y, SIZE);
    if (!cantAdd(aFish)) {
        fish.add(aFish);
    } else {
        x = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        y = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        addNewFish(x, y);
    }
}

private void addNewShark(int x, int y) {
    Shark bruce = new Shark(x, y, SIZE);
    if (!cantAdd(bruce)) {
        sharks.add(bruce);
    } else {
        x = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        y = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        addNewShark(x, y);
    }
}

private boolean hasFishNeighborUp(Shark animal) {
    for (Fish fishy : fish) {
        if (((animal.getX() - 1) == fishy.getX())
                && (animal.getY() == fishy.getY())) {
            fish.remove(fishy);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean hasFishNeighborDown(Shark animal) {
    for (Fish fishy : fish) {
        if (((animal.getX() + 1) == fishy.getX())
                && (animal.getY() == fishy.getY())) {
            fish.remove(fishy);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean hasFishNeighborLeft(Shark animal) {
    for (Fish fishy : fish) {
        if ((animal.getX() == fishy.getX())
                && ((animal.getY() - 1) == fishy.getY())) {
            fish.remove(fishy);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean hasFishNeighborRight(Shark animal) {
    for (Fish fishy : fish) {
        if ((animal.getX() == fishy.getX())
                && ((animal.getY() + 1) == fishy.getY())) {
            fish.remove(fishy);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean hasNeighborUp(Animal animal) {
    for (Fish fishy : fish) {
        return (((animal.getX() - 1) == fishy.getX()) && (animal.getY() == fishy
                .getY()));
    }
    for (Shark sharky : sharks) {
        return (((animal.getX() - 1) == sharky.getX()) && (animal.getY() == sharky
                .getY()));
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean hasNeighborDown(Animal animal) {
    for (Fish fishy : fish) {
        return (((animal.getX() + 1) == fishy.getX()) && (animal.getY() == fishy
                .getY()));
    }
    for (Shark sharky : sharks) {
        return (((animal.getX() + 1) == sharky.getX()) && (animal.getY() == sharky
                .getY()));
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean hasNeighborLeft(Animal animal) {
    for (Fish fishy : fish) {
        return ((animal.getX() == fishy.getX()) && ((animal.getY() - 1) == fishy
                .getY()));
    }
    for (Shark sharky : sharks) {
        return ((animal.getX() == sharky.getX()) && ((animal.getY() - 1) == sharky
                .getY()));
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean hasNeighborRight(Animal animal) {
    for (Fish fishy : fish) {
        return ((animal.getX() == fishy.getX()) && ((animal.getY() + 1) == fishy
                .getY()));
    }
    for (Shark sharky : sharks) {
        return ((animal.getX() == sharky.getX()) && ((animal.getY() + 1) == sharky
                .getY()));
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean cantAdd(Animal animal) {
    if(fish.size()==0 && sharks.size()==0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (Fish fishy : fish) {
        return (animal.getX() == fishy.getX())
                && (animal.getY() == fishy.getY());
    }
    if(sharks.size()==0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (Shark sharky : sharks) {
        return (animal.getX() == sharky.getX())
                && (animal.getY() == sharky.getY());
    }
    return false;
}

private void moveShark(Shark shark) {
    int rand = random.nextInt(4);
    if (hasFishNeighborUp(shark)) {
        shark.moveUp();
        shark.incEnergy();
        shark.resetStarveTime();
    } else if (hasFishNeighborDown(shark)) {
        shark.moveDown();
        shark.incEnergy();
        shark.resetStarveTime();
    } else if (hasFishNeighborLeft(shark)) {
        shark.moveLeft();
        shark.incEnergy();
        shark.resetStarveTime();
    } else if (hasFishNeighborRight(shark)) {
        shark.moveRight();
        shark.incEnergy();
        shark.resetStarveTime();
    } else if (!hasFishNeighborUp(shark) && !hasFishNeighborDown(shark)
            && !hasFishNeighborLeft(shark) && !hasFishNeighborRight(shark)) {
        if(hasNeighborUp(shark) && hasNeighborDown(shark) && hasNeighborLeft(shark) && hasNeighborRight(shark)) {
            shark.incStarveTime();
        }
        else if(rand==0 && !hasNeighborUp(shark)) {
            shark.moveUp();
            shark.incStarveTime();
        }
        else if(rand==0 && hasNeighborUp(shark)) {
            rand = 1;
        }
        else if(rand==1 && !hasNeighborDown(shark)) {
            shark.moveDown();
            shark.incStarveTime();
        }
        else if(rand==1 && hasNeighborDown(shark)) {
            rand = 2;
        }
        else if(rand==2 && !hasNeighborLeft(shark)) {
            shark.moveLeft();
            shark.incStarveTime();
        }
        else if(rand==2 && hasNeighborLeft(shark)) {
            rand = 3;
        }
        else if(rand==3 && !hasNeighborRight(shark)) {
            shark.moveRight();
            shark.incStarveTime();
        }
        else if(rand==3 && hasNeighborRight(shark)) {
            moveShark(shark);
        }
    }
}

public void moveFish(Fish fish) {
    int rand = random.nextInt(4);
    if(hasNeighborUp(fish) && hasNeighborDown(fish) && hasNeighborLeft(fish) && hasNeighborRight(fish)) {
        fish.incBreedAge();
    }
    if(rand==0 && !hasNeighborUp(fish)) {
        fish.moveUp();
        fish.incBreedAge();
    }
    else if(rand==0 && hasNeighborUp(fish)) {
        moveFish(fish);
    }
    else if(rand==1 && !hasNeighborDown(fish)) {
        fish.moveDown();
        fish.incBreedAge();
    }
    else if(rand==1 && hasNeighborDown(fish)) {
        moveFish(fish);
    }
    else if (rand == 2 && !hasNeighborLeft(fish)) {
        fish.moveLeft();
        fish.incBreedAge();
    }
    else if(rand==2 && hasNeighborLeft(fish)) {
        moveFish(fish);
    }
    else if(rand == 3 && !hasNeighborRight(fish)) {
        fish.moveRight();
        fish.incBreedAge();
    }
    else if(rand==3 && hasNeighborRight(fish)) {
        moveFish(fish);
    }
}

private void updateSharks() {   
    for(Shark sharky : sharks) {
        if(sharky.hasStarved()) {
            sharksToRemove.add(sharky);
        }
        else if(sharky.canBreed()) {
            Shark newShark = new Shark(sharky.getX(),sharky.getY(), SIZE);
            sharksToAdd.add(newShark);
        }
        moveShark(sharky);
    }
    for(Shark aShark : sharksToRemove) {
        sharks.remove(aShark);
    }
    for(Shark theShark : sharksToAdd) {
        sharks.add(theShark);
    }
}

private void updateFish() {
    for(Fish fishy : fish) {
        if(fishy.canBreed()) {
            Fish newFish = new Fish(fishy.getX(),fishy.getY(),SIZE);
            fishToAdd.add(newFish);
        }
        moveFish(fishy);
    }
    for(Fish theFish : fishToAdd) {
        fish.add(theFish);
    }
}

public void update() {
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<SIZE; j++) {
            ocean[i][j]=null;
        }
    }
    updateSharks();
    updateFish();
    for(Fish fishy : fish) {
        addFish(fishy);
    }
    for(Shark sharky : sharks) {
        addShark(sharky);
    }
}

public void print() {
    for (int x = 0; x < ocean.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < ocean[0].length; y++) {
            if (ocean[x][y] == null) {
                System.out.print(" 0 ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" "+ocean[x][y].getType()+" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `private static final int canBreed = 4` is a little confusing. The name suggests that it should be a Boolean value, but it appears to be using a magic code to represent an ability? If 4 is a code, I'd use an enum to make its purpose clearer.

Comment: `canBreed` seems to be the age at which the animal has matured. A name like `matureAge` might be better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Animal

```
private int SIZE;
```

Why do you start using uppercase here? It's no constant.

```
Animal(int xcoord, int ycoord, int t, int size) {
    x=xcoord;
```

Alternatively you can name our field `xcoord` and the constructor's argument `x`. It's equally wrong. Use just `x` for both and

```
   this.x = x;
```

This is the normal style and it's absolutely clear what argument corresponds with what field.

```
public void moveX(int dx) {
    x = x + dx;
    if(x > SIZE - 1) {
        x = 0;
    }
    if(x < 0) {
        x = SIZE - 1;
    }
}
```

This sounds wrong. It should be some kind of wrap-around, but with `dx>1` or `dx<-1`, it can lead to surprising results. What you want is probably

```
public void moveX(int dx) {
    x = sanitize(x + dx);
}

public int sanitize(int z) {
    z %= SIZE;
    if (z<0) {
        z += SIZE;
    }
    return z;
}
```

I'm using here `z` as it works for both `x` and `y`. Note the spacing and the use of `+=` instead of the more verbose `= ... +`.

```
public void moveUp() {
    moveX(-1);
}
```

Such methods are more than useless, unless you need to satisfy some external requirements. Why? They're pretty repetitive and every use of them makes your code even more repetitive.

### Fish

```
public void moveUp() {
    moveX(-1);
    breedAge ++;
}
```

I've just said it. Even more repetitive.

If there really was a need for such a method, then it should look like

```
public void moveUp() {
    moveX(-1);
    afterMove();
}
```

and be defined in `Animal` with `afterMove` being implemented differently in `Fish` and `Shark`.

## Shark

```
private ArrayList<Fish> fish;

    ...
    fish = new ArrayList<Fish>();
```

This should be

```
private final List<Fish> fish = new ArrayList<Fish>();
```

Note the use of `final` and `List` (rather than `ArrayList`).

```
Ocean(int size, int f, int s) {
```

Use proper variable names, especially in such important places as method declaration. Single letters (apart from things like `x` and `y` for coordinates) are generally frown upon. I consider them fine in something like

```
for(Fish f : fish) {
    addFish(f);
}
```

where they have no important and a very limited scope, but a method signature deserves something better. By using the convention

```
Ocean(int size, int numFish, int numShark) {
    this.size = size;
    ...
```

you save yourself the need to invent new names.

```
private void fillOcean() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numFish; i++) {
        int x = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        int y = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        addNewFish(x, y);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < numSharks; j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I guess that recycling `i` would make it clearer than using a new variable name.

```
private void addNewFish(int x, int y) {
    Fish aFish = new Fish(x, y, SIZE);
    if (!cantAdd(aFish)) {
        fish.add(aFish);
    } else {
        x = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        y = random.nextInt(SIZE);
        addNewFish(x, y);
    }
}
```

I don't like this kind of recursion. Nobody knows how deep it gets and it's rather uncommon. Moreover, you repeat here what you did in `fillOcean` above. There's a simple solution

```
while (fish.size() < numFish) {
    int x = random.nextInt(size);
    int y = random.nextInt(size);
    Fish f = new Fish(x, y, size);
    if (canAdd(f)) {
        fish.add(f);
    }
}
```

I removed the double negation `!cantAdd` and renamed `aFish` to `f`. Names like `aFish` are rather uncommon, and I find something like `newFish` needless verbose (for a variable spanning just 3 lines).

```
private boolean hasFishNeighborUp(Shark animal) {
```

Again repetitive.... and why do you call the `Shark` just `animal`?

The name `has...` sound like a getter checking some condition.... but in this process the poor fish dies. So I'd rename it.

```
private boolean hasNeighborUp(Animal animal) ...
```

Another set of four. This all needs something like an

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor enum Direction {
    UP(+1, 0),
    ...;

    private final int dx;
    private final int dy;
}
```

and a method like

```
private boolean hasNeighbor(Animal animal, Direction direction) ...
```

and some loops

```
for (Direction d : Direction.values()) ...
```

---

```
private void moveShark(Shark shark) {
```

This is very very long. And a bit wrong:

```
} else if (!hasFishNeighborUp(shark) && !hasFishNeighborDown(shark)
        && !hasFishNeighborLeft(shark) && !hasFishNeighborRight(shark)) {
```

This condition seems to be trivially true as it's in an "else-if" and all the condition has been tested already.

```
    else if(rand==0 && hasNeighborUp(shark)) {
        rand = 1;
    }
    else if(rand==1 && !hasNeighborDown(shark)) {
```

Setting `rand = 1` is a "dead store" as the condition below it won't get tested *after* it (simply "else-if").

Too long... skipping a bit.

```
for(Shark aShark : sharksToRemove) {
    sharks.remove(aShark);
}
```

You need no *field* `sharksToRemove`, it should be a local variable. This field grows and grows as sharks (to be removed) get added to it and never removed.

Use `sharks.removeAll(sharksToRemove)`.

```
public void print()
```

Implement `toString()` instead, it's just a little bit longer and can be used in debugger and elsewhere.

---

```
private void addFish(Fish fish) {
    ocean[fish.getX()][fish.getY()] = fish;
}
```

This adds no fish as the `List<Fish> fish` does not change. It only updates `ocean` to reflect the `fish`'s position.

```
public void update() ...
```

You first clean the `ocean`, then you do something else, and finally you repopulate the `ocean`. Can't you bring the two ocean operations together? Can't you reuse `update` in the constructor?

Answer (score 10):

I'm not a Java expert, and I've only looked over this code a little bit, so I only have a few tips.

- Why are your `moveDirection` methods in the specific animal classes inherited from `Animal`? I'd recommend implementing a simple `move` method in the animal class that allows the animal to move in a specific direction. Here's an example.

---

```
public void move(xAmount, yAmount) {
    this.xcoord += xAmount;
    this.ycoord += yAmount;
}
```

---

- Some of your indentation is odd. You should have any code inside you classes indented. It looks much clearer than the current format.
- Why have the coordinate variables named `xcoord` and `ycoord`? Simply naming them `x` and `y` would suffice.
- Finally, add some comments describing what certain methods/classes do. It'll make reading your code much, much easier.

That's about all I can come up with. If there's anything else that you want me to cover, just mention it in the comments, and I'll see what I can do.